# The cardinal directions on a flat world?

Tags: planets, map-making, navigation

This is a simple question.

What would a civilization on a flat world call the directions on a compass?

Comment: Your question makes it sound like the words we use for the directions on a compass have any particular meaning beyond that ascribed to them by common usage. How is this question, as it stands, not idea generation?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Because I'm trying to come up with world specific name for the directions. The Discworld  series has rimward and hubward for north and south, in adition to turnwise and widdershins which I must assume are east and west.

Comment: We may not live on a flat world, but we use flat maps constantly and North/South/West/East works fine there (and also when playing bridge).  So I'd think the same convention would hold on a flat world, unless the language evolved completely differently?

Comment: @aroth I'll take that into consideration. But I was trying to come up with something a bit more world specific.

Comment: What is the shape of said flat world?

Comment: How does your compass works on a flat world?

Comment: @XandarTheZenon a disk.

Comment: @user6760 the center of the island is the Axis pole.

Comment: No answer just an interesting fact: use 2 compasses to find distant from the axle! One moves while the other hold it infront of you straight.

Comment: On discworld, there are entities to give these directions names, like the rim and the hub.  Without providing us any such world information, there's not really all that much we can do better than the North South East and West, or perhaps those same names in another language.

Comment: @Trismegistus Discworld also has the additional aspect that the sun does _not_ rise and set in a consistent geographic location (on the contrary, the seasons are determined by the rotation of the disc relative to the sun's fixed orbit - it is warmer [summer] when the sun rises or sets at the nearest point on the rim.) If your world doesn't share this aspect, then "East" (where the sun rises) might well exist on it, with a rectilinear system based on this and the fixed climate bands to the colder north and south.

Comment: The description of this question seems meaningless to me. People call directions whatever they call them. North South East and West work even better when thinking of a flat map than they do on a globe, because they reference a grid system, which on a globe means that following any direction is a curve, and any direction between one of the four cardinal directions (e.g. NW, or SSE) isn't even a great circle (q.v.) but a turning course on the globe. Etc. I don't see how this question contains enough information for an actual answer that's not based on people arbitrarily making up details.

Comment: How sun works on your world? Does it rotate around flat plate, at the night hidden below? Is it being swallowed through a hole in the center? Is it in same place, just turning on and off? Is being dragged on arc above the world?

Comment: @PeterMasiar The sun appears to be in the place waxing on and off.

Comment: Diskworld uses polar coordinates. Turnwise and Widdershins are clockwise and anticlockwise, or vice versa. (The pole is the big mountain in the middle).

Comment: @nigel222 I know but how do represent  Turnwise and Widdershins  on a map or compass? How do you travel turnwise to get to the other side of a city. North,south,east,west, are forward,backward,left,right, so what are  Turnwise and Widdershins.

Comment: @Trismegistus The map is circular with the mountain in the middle. You know where you are. You are facing away from the mountain. You rotate your disk-shaped map so its representation of the place you are looking at is towards the top relative to the mountain. Clockwise is on your right. Or you face the mountain. Clockwise in now on your left. You'd probably use a similar map on Earth in Antarctica were Antarctica habitable. For a small patch like a city it would simply have Rimward marked as on Earth we have North marked. Face Rimward, Clockwise is (almost) the same as East.

Answer (score 9):

I'm going to avoid Sir Terry's nomenclature, because it is so tied into the Discworld series I think it'd stand out like a sore thumb if anyone else used it:

**Axle** - towards the centre. Also could actually be the centre; the flat world equivalent of the Arctic - leading logically to:

**Antaxle** - the edge, and towards the edge.

**Spinwards** - obviously with the spin.

**Backwards** - against the spin.

Not really happy with "backwards" though. You could follow the Axle / Antaxle scheme and have **Antispinwards**, but I like that even less.

I was also thinking you could also use nautical terms if your world is ocean-heavy enough for sailing terms to have plausibly entered common usage:

**Runwards** - in the direction of spin; running is sailing with the wind, so implies it is the "easy" direction - the one that goes with the flow, as it were.

**Beatwise / tackwise / tackwards** - against the spin, again using the sailing terms for sailing into the wind - going *against* the flow.

I quite like "tackwards" as it implies "backwards" while sounding quite fantasy-esque.

Just realised there are two very obvious possible terms for the radial directions:

**Out** and **In**

---

I used [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_nautical_terms#B) to ensure I remembered my terms correctly; it's a treasure trove of nautical words!

Comment: Thank you. I am having a hard time grasping how spin and counter-spin would on a map or compass.

Comment: @Trismegistus - Oh, okay, I see your point now. Using the rotational directions is nice and logical but not that practical; to sail due spinwards you'd actually have  to be constantly adjusting your course. I can't really think of any way round that without arbitrarily assigning a zero point and just travelling via bearings based on that; which is basically a NESW scheme again.

Comment: I still think that the radial directions would be useful in common language -- "oh, Edgelanders. Cheats, the lot of 'em" - but in terms of directions, not so much; it's unlikely you'll ever be travelling due Edge unless you start at the centre.

Comment: You always have to assign an arbitrary point. The Greenwich Meridian is our basis for navigation, but still ultimately arbitrary. Another point can be assigned relative miles or degrees with/against the turn and miles in/out.

Comment: Agreed, but then what instructions do you issue your steersman? You don't want to sail due spin because your course would be a curve. You need a terminology that allows you to point the ship in a straight line to the destination. Could you have a compass that points due Hub and use that to get a single bearing? I can't quite get my head round it.

Comment: @user16295 So after mulling, I think I've got it; wherever you are, the Hub is zero "latitude". You get the destination point using the degrees "longitude" from your "Greenwich" and the distance from the Hub. You get your current position in the same format. Then you can do maths to get the compass bearing to sail. So you never use the "spin" directions to actually sail, just to calculate points to get a compass bearing. Is that right?

Comment: You sail with the winds and currents. There will be specific courses to certain destinations. Historic navigation is fascinating and involves a lot of point and hope.

Comment: We use [great circles](http://www.gcmap.com/mapui?P=SFO-NRT-SIN,SFO-HKG-SIN) to navigate using direct paths on the surface of sphere. Something similar would apply.

Comment: @KellyThomas On a flat world, surely a straight line on a map is a straight line on the world? You wouldn't need great circles; there are no different projections to worry about - a flat map is just a perfect scale diagram of the actual landscape.

Comment: One of the unintuitive aspects of following most great circles is that while you are traveling is a straight line (i.e. no turning left or right) your bearing will change along the journey.

Comment: Ah, that's very interesting. So there is actually precedent for sailing using directions that vary along your journey.

Comment: @Whelkaholism The optimal course for sailing ships probably depends heavily on the navigation method. On Earth, it is a _rhumb line_ (constant bearing) - which is close enough to the shortest course at mid-latitudes that it was fine to use. A constant bearing to the center of a disc is a _logarithmic spiral_, rather than a straight line. They may have navigation tools designed to calculate such a course. It also may depend on how the prevailing winds work.

Comment: 'Spinwards' and 'backwards' seem problematic, as I'd imagine that an observer standing on the surface of the flat world would perceive themselves as being stationary.  Similar to how observers standing on Earth don't directly perceive the planet's rotation.  The spin will only be observable by looking at the motion of objects in the sky, and that motion will be reversed compared to the actual direction of spin (i.e. the Earth rotates West to East, while celestial objects appear travel East ro West).

Comment: @aroth so I might as well stick with the earthly directions.

Comment: Names: Out and In are good. Clockwise and Anticlockwise are in everyday use. If too long then make up say Uleft and Eright meaning left and right when you are facing Out. (U pronounced Oo = W in Welsh ...)

Answer (score 2):

You've already answered your own question in the comments but I'll elaborate because I'm not sure you've understood them properly.

*Assuming your planet is a spinning disk* (elephants and turtle not required, what does the turtle stand on anyway*)

**Rimward**
Towards the nearest point on the edge

**Hubward**
Towards the centre of the disk, the hub of the spin.

**Turnwise**
In the direction of the spin. You could replace this with clockwise.

**[Widdershins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widdershins)**
Against the direction of the spin.
This is an old English word meaning anticlockwise and implies the "wrong direction".

**The Compass**
"[On the Disc, if you enchant a needle it will point to the hub, where the magical field is strongest](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XQ8MctA_1xQC&lpg=PA12&ots=2cYapnLcTI&dq=Enchant%20a%20needle%20and%20it%20points%20towards%20the%20Hub&pg=PA12#v=onepage&q&f=false)", perpendicular to the needle is the tangent to the Turnwise/Widdershins circle.

**The Zero Meridian**
This is key to navigation, the arbitrary point from which all others are measured. The zero meridian, as per the Greenwich Meridian lies on the line from the hub to the rim through the dominant sea trading city. Everything else is calculated relative to that position. Absolute Grid references can be given as degrees round the circle from that point (Turnwise or Widdershins) and miles from the hub.

It should be noted that navigation on open water is going to be really hard. If you're actually concerned about accuracy in such things you'll have to build a system such that it can be realistically done. Or just ignore it completely, this is probably the better bet.

<sub>*It's turtles all the way down</sub>

Comment: Sea turtle are great swimmer. You can imagine that "the sea of stars" is slightly more than a metaphore.

Comment: I asked the question as a way to see if anyone had cardinal direction for a flat world. For north and south I  was going to use something like Edge and Axis. What I didn't have was names for east and west. I am having a hard time imagining what Spinward and Widdershins look like on a map.

Comment: Imagine the globe from a view directly over the North Pole. The pole itself is the hub, East and West now map to Turnwise and Widdershins. Moving with the sun is against the turn, though the discworld spins for seasons rather than days. They're not straight, they go round the circle.

Comment: "Enchant a needle and it points towards the Hub", perpendicular to the needle is the tangent to the Turnwise/Widdershins circle.

Comment: This might help [visualize](http://i.imgur.com/iCIMXWk.jpg). ([source](https://nordpil.com/portfolio/mapsgraphics/arctic-topography/))

Comment: "The turtle SWIMS. It's a TURTLE."

Answer (score 2):

If compasses work then the Bridge directions are fine. We did not have to discover the north pole to have a north. If the sun rises and sets in the same general places every day then east and west are knowable and the same as ours.

But remember the earth is not disc shaped but flat and square so it has four actual corners like the bible clearly states. [image]

Comment: This image immediately brought to my mind the concept of the [gravity well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravity_well).

Comment: My thoughts were that the very center of the island is the axis-Pole.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling science

Comment: That was a joke about the bible, right?

Comment: @XandarTheZenon every religion has embarrassing proof texts and history.  For us Jews one of them is  Isaiah 11:12 for y'all Christians who decided to run with it Revelation 7:1. Islam on the other hand, says it shaped like an Ostrich egg Al-Qur’an 79:30. It is a bit unfair because they wrote their stuff much later.

Comment: Figurative. Those verses are speaking figuratively. I really should read the bible more often, it's quite interesting.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon you and I may call those verses figurative, but some people still take them literally.

Comment: @Separatrix You know, if you pick four arbitrary areas and have them at angles of 109.5 degrees you get four evenly spaced corners. Food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

Island nations like Hawai'i use it all the time: ocean-side (makai) and volcano-side (mauka, toward the center of the island).

So your flat world would have one important direction towards the center.

Comment: What of east and west.

Comment: East and West are relater to the movements of the sun. So it depends how sun works on your world. Does it rotate around flat plate? Is it being swallowed in the center? Is it in same place, just turning on and off?

Comment: The world slow turns, the sun always appears to be directly overhead, rather rise or set the sun's light waxes and wanes.

Comment: The sun appears to be in the same place waxing on and waning off.

Answer (score 1):

Given fact in many languages names of directions are referring to position of sun on sky, and they are originated in times when people believed earth is flat. There is big possibility, directions will be same as ours.